# "25 apples on the table."

Tags: sentence-construction

> 25 apples on the table.

Don't we put "are" between the 2 words. Or what is grammatical issue in here?

Comment: It depends on the context. You can say "25 apples are on the table", or "There are 25 apples on the table" or "We can eat the 25 apples on the table"

Comment: If it's intended to be a sentence, then it needs a verb. If it's a sentence constituent (eg _there are 25 apples on the table_) or a sentence fragment (eg the answser to a question) it is fine.

Answer (score 6):

> Don't we put "are" between the 2 words.

It depends on the **context**, e.g.

*What do you see on the table?

I see 25 apples on the table.*

*What is on the table?

25 apples are on the table.*

*What is on the table?

25 apples.*

*What can you see?

I can see a table and 25 apples on the table.*

Comment: What's the name of that picture on the wall: *“25 apples on the table.”*, though more likely, something like that wouldn't use the definite article: *“25 apples on a table.”*

Answer (score 3):

Your original statement lacks a main verb. "are" is used as a [main verb here](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/auxiliary_verbs.htm).

> Linking Verbs as Main Verbs

> When we think of verbs, we tend to envision action verbs like "run," "walk," and "eat." You can actually "see" someone "doing" something. But, linking verbs can also act as main verbs.

> Some of the most popular linking verbs include: am, is, are, was and were.

> [ ... ]

> One of the core functions of linking verbs is to connect the subject of the sentence to more information.

> Source: https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/verbs/what-is-the-main-verb-in-a-sentence.html

If no extra information is given, the grammatically correct sentence for "25 apples on the table" should include "are":

> 25 apples are on the table.